# How can I include jasperreport (jrxml) in my report using asp.net mvc and https://www.jsreports.com library

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using ASP.NET and https://www.jsreports.com jsreports for generate a report want to use it like this

```
 orderData = $.parseJSON(stringData);
        // Alias JasperReportDef for brevity
        var JasperReportDef = jsreports.integrations.jasper.JasperReportDef;
        // Fetch .jrxml file
        $.get("/Content/Images/report4.jrxml", function(jrxml) {
            // Convert to jsreports format
            var reportDef = JasperReportDef.fromJRXML(jrxml);
            // Create designer
            var designer = new jsreports.Designer({
                container: $("#textToPrint"),
                data_sources: [orderData],   // Will use the embedded data source information
                report: reportDef
            });
        });
```

but when I build it, I have this error :
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:4732/Content/Images/report4.jrxml